# Is it possible to redefine a function after its setter is modified in the parent function?

Tags: javascript

I can only change the code within `function a`. For example if I have:

`Object.defineProperty(window, 'App', { get: console.log.bind(null, 'World') });`

WeChat will take my code and turn it into:

```
__wxJSEngine.App = console.log.bind(null, 'Hello')

g.App = __wxJSEngine.App

Object.defineProperty(g, 'App', {
  set: ()=> {
    console.error("You are not allow to modify App");
  }
})

((App, Function, window) => {
  'use strict';
  function a() {
    'use strict';
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'App', { get: console.log.bind(null, 'World') });
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
  }
  function b() {
    'use strict';
    App();
  }
  a();
  b();
})(g.App, ()=>(()=>({})), undefined);
```

Now, I want to modify App in `function a`, so I can change its behavior in `function b`, so it would print `World` instead of `Hello`.

Comment: Try `Object.assign()` instead of `Object.define()`

Comment: But `Object.assign` which object?

Comment: Wasn't `params = {...}` in `function a()`?

Comment: What params? `const App` was defined outside of `function a`.

Comment: Your last [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55452265/revisions#)  
 (only a few minutes old) has `params` in `func a()`. Anyways that's irrelevant. See my post concerning `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 0):

Given how the code is structured, function `b` **will not** use the global `App`, but directly `sandbox`'s argument.
This argument is accessible to `a`'s scope and is not declared as a *const*.

So all you need to do, is to overwrite the value of the variable `App` from inside `a`, so that `b` can use your own value.

```js
window.App = console.log.bind(null, 'Hello')

Object.defineProperty(window, 'App', {
  set: ()=> {
    console.error("You are not allow to modify App");
  }
})

const sandbox = (App, Function, window) => {
  'use strict';
  function a() {
    'use strict';
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
    App = console.log.bind(null, 'World');
    // *** I can only modify codes within this block ***
  }
  function b() {
    'use strict';
    App();
  }
  a();
  b();
};

sandbox(window.App, ()=>(()=>({})), undefined);
```

Now, this won't change `window.App` value, but since this property has been defined as non-writable, non-configurable, there is nothing you can do to set it to something else.

Comment: `App = console.log.bind(null, 'World');` will result at an error.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Not with what you gave. You can press the "Run the snippet" button and see by yourself.

Comment: It looks like when I updated my question last time I made a mistake. Let me fix it.

Comment: @AeroWang updated too, just the same. WHat is the error you get? If it's "You are not allow to modify App" then it means that `sandbox`'s first argument is not declared as `App`, and you are screwed, as per the final note of my answer.

Comment: Yeah the code you see is a simplified version of 80+K lines of sandbox in WeChat. I am just trying to recreate the sandbox but it looks like the original version is not allowed to run in a browser so I changed the code into the code above but it doesn't block App = xxx anymore. :/

Comment: And so you decide to downvote people that took time to answer your question because you weren't able to give them the correct description of your problem? Sounds harsh, at least. There is no way anyone can answer your question if you are not able to ask it properly. How do you want **us** to guess what's in these 80+K of lines?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but zer00ne sounds aggressive and his answer is simply wrong. Yeah, I guess it is not possible to use regular javascript to recreate the sandbox running in a browser. You probably have to download wechat's SDK and create an App running plugin under 2.6.4 and try to redefine App to see how to get it to work.

Comment: @AeroWang I got irritated because I told you a couple of times that you need to post a [mcve]. You get back with what you put in. The effort put into the OP is not sufficient nor is the gratitude.

Answer (score -1):

Object composition is when you copy properties from one object to another. [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is the goto method.

```js
const App = func => ({
  salutation: () => {
    return `${func.user}: ${func.HW}`;
  }
});

const a = (user, greeting) => {
  let func = {
    user,
    HW: greeting
  };
  return Object.assign(func, App(func));
};

const A = a('zer00ne', 'World');
console.log(A.user);
console.log(A.salutation());
```

Comment: Yeah, I am not allowed to modify codes outside of function a. `function a(func) {
    'use strict';
    Object.define(???, 'App', {get: console.log.bind(null, 'World') });
  }`

Comment: That's just to show you **how to use `Object.assign()`**.  My code is proof of concept (ie it works). If you can actually provide a [mcve] I can probably refactor it by changing function `a()` only.

Comment: Yeah I know how `Object.assign` works...please update your answer.

Comment: Yeah you obviously do not understand what a [mcve] is. There's nothing to update on my side until you update your side to a [mcve]. Doesn't matter anyhow Kaiido has answer.

Comment: It's laughable to say Kaiido's answer doesn't work. I'm pretty sure you failed to understand or just don't want to put in the effort or your question is unanswerable and needs to be edited (perhaps a [mcve]?)

Comment: I tried, but I guess you will have to download a wechat dev tool to get my original code to run (in which you think is not Verifiable, but it was). The current version runs in browsers but doesn't block modification of App.

Comment: I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I think the JS engine in wechat perhaps is slightly different. It allows the code to run while in chrome it would fail.